# What is that noise? It’s a ... / That's a

Tags: pronouns

Is it common to answer the questions [What is that...?] --> [It's ...]?

Are the answers [That's a train.], [That's a hospital.] rare or mistaken in this case?

> What is **that noise**? **It’s** a train.
>
> What is **that building**? **It’s** a hospital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so rare, nor mistaken.  It's fine to use "it" since the building has been mentioned and you just need a pronoun.  It is also fine to reply  "a train" and not make a sentence.

You might want to use "that" in a more complex answer

> That's just a train, but listen again and when it's gone you might be able to hear the nightingale.